# Repeat a function N times in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to create a function that would return a function which is n-times composed function of f over parameter x, i.e. f(f(f ... f(x) ...)).
Here is my code:

```
def repeated(f: Int => Int, n: Int) = {
   var tek: Int => Int = f

   for (i <- 0 to n) {
     tek = x => f(tek(x))
   }
   tek
}
```

I know this is not right way to do this in Scala, I just want to find out what's happening behind the scenes. 
Calling it like `repeated(x => x + 1, 5)(1)` would result in stack overflow.
What I have notice in debugger is that line inside for loop is executed after repeated is finished. It seems like lazy initiation, maybe body of for loop is a lambda passed by name?

Comment: Note, this is already in the standard library as [Stream.iterate](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$.html#iterate[A](start:A,len:Int)(f:A=%3EA):scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]) or [Iterator.iterate](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/Iterator$.html#iterate[T](start:T)(f:T=%3ET):Iterator[T]) (followed by `take n`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `x => f(tek(x))` is closing over the *variable* `tek`. Once the inner for-loop runs at least once, your `tek` becomes self-referential, because `tek = x => f(tek(x))` calls itself, which causes unbounded recursion and `StackOverflowError`.

If you wanted to do it with a `for`-loop, you could introduce a local immutable helper variable to break the recursion:

```
def repeated(f: Int => Int, n: Int) = {
   var tek: Int => Int = identity

   for (i <- 1 to n) {
     val g = tek
     tek = x => f(g(x))
   }
   tek
}
```

Note that you had at least two applications of `f` too much in your code:

1. You didn't start with identity for `n = 0`
2. You iterated from `0` to `n`, that is, `(n + 1)` times.

A much simpler solution would have been:

```
def repeated[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A = { (a0: A) =>

  var res: A = a0
  for (i <- 1 to n) {
    res = f(res)
  }
  res
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In pure FP:

```
def repeated[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A =
  (0 until n).foldLeft(identity[A] _)((ff, _) => ff.andThen(f))
```

(also works if `n=0` - becomes `identity`)

Or, if you don't like iterating over a `Range` (which I think wouldn't be much less performant than alternatives), manual tail recursion:

```
def repeated[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A = {
  @tailrec def aux(acc: A => A, n: Int): A => A = {
    if(n > 0) aux(acc.andThen(f), n - 1)
    else acc
  }

  aux(identity, n)
}
```

EDIT: there's also the Stream version, as @Karl Bielefeldt mentioned. Should be about about as performant, but of course the best way to choose is to benchmark with your usecase:

```
def repeated[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A =
  Stream.iterate(identity[A] _)(_.andThen(f)).apply(n)
```

EDIT 2: if you have Cats:

```
def repeated[A](f: A => A, n: Int): A => A =
  MonoidK[Endo].algebra[A].combineN(f, n)
```